# How to remove parent node keeping the child node in outliner

Tags: mesh, outliner

community. I've a model that a person gave to me that has some unnecessary nodes in it. The problem is that I would like to remove the parent node, keeping its children. This may be approached (this is what I think) by moving each child node to a common node, grouping them together, so they're safe.

I'll show you how is the graph:
[image]

As you can observe, I have the "Root" node, which contains each mesh that composes this model. The issue is that each mesh is a direct child of an empty object.

My request is removing all the empty objects and keep meshes under the "Root" node. How could I approach that with blender 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this script:

```
import bpy


for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    
    if ob.type == "EMPTY":
        bpy.data.objects.remove(ob, do_unlink=True)
```

> NOTE: be aware, this only deletes the empty. If the empty had a
> location/rotation unequal to zero and the child has no
> location/rotation info, it could happen that after running the script
> all objects are at the origin point. But you said, you only want to
> delete the empties. If you want to keep the location, you should
> update your question (or if you are fair, ask a new question)

Comment: This script will break the relationship hierarchy. If you have this relationship *root -> empty_1 -> plane* and you delete *empty_1* then the result is *root*, *plane*. The *root* has no more children and the *plane* is an orphan and sibling of root. The expected result is *root -> plane*